# Zend Form instantiation failing silently in white screen of death

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, autoload, router

Zend newbie trying to configure and use Zend_Form.

Just for the record I'm on Zend Framework Version: 1.11.1 on Win XP running Apache 2.something. I'm working on a site which for the most part works just fine. (Somebody else started it. I have to extend it).

I am having trouble in the area of forms and am trying to introduce Zend_Form in the hope that this will somehow simplify matters. But trying to use Zend_Form is presenting problems of it's own.

When I try to instantiate the first test form, I'm getting the white screen of death -- without even an error message.

Data as follows:

```
Dir Structure:  
MYAPPNAME  
....controllers  
....forms  
....models  
....services  
....views
```

Bootstrap.php contains:

```
protected function _initAutoLoading()
{
$loader = new Zend_Loader_Autoloader_Resource(array(
'namespace' => 'MYAPPNAME',
'basePath' => APPLICATION_PATH . '/modules/MYAPPNAME',
));
$loader->addResourceTypes(array(
  'model' => array(
'path' => 'models',
'namespace' => 'Model'),
  'form' => array(
'path' => 'forms',
'namespace' => 'Form'),
  'service' => array(
'path' => 'services',
'namespace' => 'Service')));
}
```

This works fine for models with names like:

```
class MYAPPNAME_Model_DataRecordName extends Doctrine_Record
{
 etc...
```

But it seems to be failing miserably for forms ... although mind you, this is my first pass at using Zend_Form.

My form is defined in file MYAPPNAME/forms/Formtest.php:

```
<?php

class MYAPPNAME_Form_Formtest extends Zend_Form
{
 public function init($action){

  $this->setAction($action)
   ->setMethod('post')
   ->setAttrib('id', 'formtestForm');

  $email = $this->addElement( 'text', 'email',
   array('label', => 'EMail'));
  )

  $submit = $this->addElement('submit', 'Submit and Be Free!');
 }// End init
} // End class def
```

The form is being displayed in a view defined as:

```
<div class=""testForm">
<p style="margin-top:20px; margin-bottom:10px"">Explanatory Text</p>
<h2>This is a Form Test</h2>

<?php echo $this->formResponse; ?>
<?php echo $this->form; ?>

<hr>
<p>FORM ABOVE THIS BAR</p>
</div>
```

The view works just fine.

It is being managed by an action (in a working controller) defined as:

```
 public function formtestAction(){
  echo "formtestAction: ENTERED";

  $form = new MYAPPNAME_Form_Formtest('ThisController/formtest2');    
  //$form =  "<p>GARBAGE DATA</p>";

  if(!empty($form)){$this->view->form = $form;}
  else{
   $form = "<p>THE FORM VAR IS EMPTY</p>";
   $this->view->form = $form;

   $formResponse = "<p>INSTANTIATION FAILED</p>";
   $this->view->formResponse = $formResponse;
  }
 }
 public function formtest2Action(){
  echo "formtest2Action: ENTERED";
 }
```

If I comment out both the form instantiation and the garbage data lines, I get valid output in the view. If I set $form to "GARBAGE DATA" I also get valid predictable output.

However when I try to instantiate the form object I get the white screen of death containing only "formtestAction: ENTERED" (from the echo statement at the top.)

I am going slowly mad.

I can't figure out if this is an autoloader problem, a routing problem, an object instantiation problem, or what.

I'd be very much obliged for any advice.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Did you check your PHP logs? If you're hitting some PHP fatal error, you are very likely to end up with a blank screen. Besides, fatal errors won't land in your application log (as uncaught exceptions do), they'll go straight to the PHP log.

Answer (score 1):

With Zends, I've run into that several times, and it usually is something annoying as a superflous comma. In

... 'basePath' => APPLICATION_PATH . '/modules/MYAPPNAME',));

it looks just like on of those. Only a quick look, but you might check it anyway.

HTH,
Marcus

Comment: could you accept my post as answer (for our internal reputationhunt)  ;)Regards,

Answer (score 0):

mtoepper: Very close. Good catch!

It was indeed an extra comma, only it was in the Form class definition -- preventing successful object instantiation.

These silent failures are VERY annoying.